# facing problem on passing url of google photos photo in NetworkImage("")

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

```
SocketException (SocketException: Connection failed (OS Error: Operation not permitted, errno = 1), address = photos.google.com, port = 443)
```

this the thrown error

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyDrawer extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyDrawer({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      child: ListView(
        children: [
          UserAccountsDrawerHeader(accountName: Text("Ankur Kumar Dubey"),
           accountEmail: Text("ankurkrdn9@gmail.com"),
           currentAccountPicture: const CircleAvatar(
            backgroundImage: NetworkImage("https://photos.google.com/u/1/album/AF1QipO4Nkg8rvcMLOStg5apTabquCIP4zWeWk3cV0VM/photo/AF1QipN2o1rDEznIccKZZuNIrj3raQQPJbaBng6Ec9jS"),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

try to display an image from google photos using NetworkImage...........